# mysql query: pull all rows where field2 has 01, 02, or 04 as any part of it

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
  WHERE field1 IS NULL 
    AND (field2 LIKE '%01%' OR 
         field2 LIKE '%02%' OR 
         field2 LIKE '%04%'
        )
```

The goal is to pull all rows where field2 has 01, 02, or 04 as any part of it. field2 typically has comma separated values like 01,02,03 or sometimes just a single 02. However, when I run this query, I get back only one result that has 01,02,03,04 as the value, and it isn't the only one in the table with that exact same data.

This is essentially what the table looks like:

|id|field1  |field2             
| 1|  NULL|01,02,03,04
| 2|  NULL|01,02,03,04
| 3|  NULL|01,02,04

Comment: but is it the only one where field 1 is null??

Comment: every row in the database currently has field1 set as null

Comment: So if you drop `field1 is null` you get the same results?

Comment: just tested, yes if i remove the null part of the query i get the same results

Comment: can you post a few rows of sample data?

Comment: not sure how to post sample mysql data on here.

Comment: Hmm, well it should work as you're expecting, unless there's further parts of the WHERE field or other info we're missing out on.  Just tested it locally and it works fine for me.

Comment: run a query and copy the output and post it to your question.

Comment: Ok Rudu, I'll dig into it some more. Thanks

Comment: Rudu, you're right, it works. It was an error in my code that was resetting the variable in the while loop. I had = instead of .=  Thanks for helping me out on this one guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use REGEXP function:

```
SELECT *     
  FROM table     
 WHERE field1 IS NULL       
   AND (field2 REGEXP '0[124]')
```

e.g:

```
SELECT *
  FROM  (
                 SELECT 'SKJDFHSKDJF01KJSAKSJFHK DSFKJHSKDFJ' INFO
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 'SKJDFHSKDJF02KJSAKSJFHK DSFKJHSKDFJ' INFO
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 'SKJDFHSKDJF03KJSAKSJFHK DSFKJHSKDFJ' INFO
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 'SKJDFHSKDJF04KJSAKSJFHK DSFKJHSKDFJ' INFO
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 'SKJDFHSKDJF0KJSAKSJFHK DSFKJHSKDFJ' INFO
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 'SKJDFHSKDJF09KJSAKSJFHK DSFKJHSKDFJ' INFO
                ) b
 WHERE INFO REGEXP '0[124]'
```

Comment: what if it isn't a range? the query could easily be 01,03,05.

Comment: Since OP has stated that he was looking for occurance of 01, 02, 03,04 I have used the range [0-4]. This can be tweaked easily if there is a change in the requirement.

Comment: Update the post.. to pick all the records for which field2 contains either 01 or 02 or 04

Comment: what happens when you reach 10?

Comment: Ok.. So if I understand correctly you want to match all the records that contain a numeric value which are prefixed with 0. Is this correct?

Comment: Since your query technically works as well, I'll choose it as best answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE field1 IS NULL 
AND (field2 LIKE '%01%' OR field2 LIKE '%02%' OR field2 LIKE '%03%' OR field2 LIKE '%04%')
```

It's checking against field1 being NULL...do the ones you expect have a null value in field1?